# GDI count stable near 100 but Handle count keep increasing

Tags: c#, winforms

In our application, all the cells of rows are user controls which got initialized while paint

if you scroll many times or maximize /minimize, it tried to redraw cells, row wise and handle count peeks and application crashes.

question here: when I scroll a bit, for every row , it calls onpaint() but rows which are now moved out of view,(only 20 rows visible in maximized window) how can they be disposed ?

UI constructor called once, when you load but after that only paint got triggered.

Consider a Grid with every cell as user controls. If I maximize/minimize the window or scroll the grid, every control gets re initiate causing handle leak though GDI count remains steady.

Comment: Creating controls in OnPaint() sounds like a *really bad idea*. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You should rephrase your problem, if you simply want to initialize your controls, don't place code in `OnPaint`, you may want to talk more about **when you want to initialize your controls** so that we can give you some `event names`.

Answer (score 2):

`OnPaint` is usually called *a lot* of times and not under your control. Creating controls within `OnPaint` is not a good idea therefore. (In your case, there must be a lot of identical controls at the same place, i guess)

Use the form's constructor, the `Form.Load` event or any user-driven event (click on buttons, menus, toolbars, ...) for creating controls.

Comment: just giving example to explain it further. Let's say , I have a grid, bind with 50 rows. At one point of time, 20 rows [row 1-20] are visible with a vertical scroll bar. if i scroll down slightly row [3-22] is visible now. Can I dispose row 1 and row 2 and with which event ?

Comment: @user2673744: If a user scrolls, he usually don't want to kill the invisible rows, that would be a unexpected behavior. Do you mean the `DataGridView` control? If so, then take a look at [`DataGridView.Rows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx) and the [`RowsAdded` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded.aspx)